# tcsh: Bad : modifier in $ ( )

Tags: shell, tcsh, modifier

I would like to pass the last argument given to my tcsh script. I noticed, by testing with echo, that

```
echo ${*: -1:1}
```

returns the LAST argument in a series or arguments. Great!

Issue is that when **I try to put it in an if statement**, or appending to it, I receive the "Bad : modifier in $ ( )" error. Why is this?

```
if ( -r ${*: -1:1}) then
    echo "You have read permissions"
else
```

or, same issue with:

```
if ( ${*: -1:1}:e != tex) then
    exit 2
endif
```

*I tried* putting

```
${*: -1:1}
```

in extra brackets, but to no avail. I also tried setting a variable

```
set last = {*: -1:1}
```

and then calling $last in the if statement, but that gave me a "Missing }" error.

Thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: `${*: -1:1}` doesn't work in `echo` for me either ... This looks more like bourne shell syntax, and not csh? ... I think this is the sort of thing where you really run into the limits of what you can do with csh, it's an ad-hoc parser, and can all sorts of surprising things...

Comment: You're definitely right. I found a solution using awk in tcsh :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using

```
set Y = `echo $* | awk -F " " '{print $NF}'`
```

instead for my last argument, and this is compatible with tcsh. Solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you answered your own question but there is a way in `tcsh` (and `csh`) as well:

```
set count=$#argv
echo "There are $count arguments"
set last="${argv[$#argv]}"
echo "The last argument is $last"
```

If you want to extract *words* from *lists* in `csh` just make sure you use braces `{}`.

**Test:**

```
$ ./lastarg.csh 'a b' 'c d' 'e  f'
There are 3 arguments
The last argument is e  f
```